# Turning Safari Web Clips into HTML

Tags: macos, web-applications, safari, widget, web-clips

Safari's "Web Clip" feature is nice because you can take a section of a web page and access it dynamically from the desktop. This is especially cool when you are using it to "save" streaming videos and the like. What I want to do is embed one of these into an HTML page. However, unlike real widgets that are coded/WYSIWYGed, Safari doesn't really store any source code for the Web Clips; instead it does something to the effect of hard coding it every time the Dashboard starts up.

Is there any way to turn a Web Clip into HTML? Through Dashcode or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing it hard codes is a URL to the original content. These are stored in ~/Library/Preferences/widget-com.apple.widget.web-clip.plist